# simulated call onMouseDown in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onmousedown

There is a div element on the page, by clicking on it a menu with a choice of the displayed number of elements is created.

Menu:

[image: menu]

How to call this action through the console (onMouseDown React)?
Code:
[image: code]

Comment: I am writing a chrome extension for the site, and the first step I need is to show all the elements on the site. The menu is already written to React on the onMouseDown event, click does not work.

Answer (score 1):

In the console you want to grab your element and then use a dispatch event to simulate a `mouseover` or `click`

```
var div = document.querySelector("#myDiv");
var myEventToDispatch = new MouseEvent("click"); //or "mousedown", whichever you need
div.dispatchEvent(myEventToDispatch);
```

These three lines in your console should do the trick.
Checkout: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent for more options

Comment: I am writing a chrome extension for the site, and the first step I need is to show all the elements on the site. The menu is already written to React on the onMouseDown event, click does not work.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution, works in practice. The menu implementation on the site consisted of several nested divs and one input. None of these elements responded to the click () function. The solution below solved my problem and the next steps I needed.

```
<pre><code>
var MENU = IFrame.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName("class box menu")[0]; // getElementsById, getElementsByTag[0] ....
MENU = MENU.getElementsByTagName("div");
var MaxList = MENU[1].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
if(MaxList != undefined)
{
    if(MENU[0].textContent != "100 items")
    {
        // focus menu
        MaxList.focus();
        var e = new KeyboardEvent(
            "keydown", 
            {
                bubbles : true, 
                cancelable : true, 
                key : "ArrowDown", 
                char : "ArrowDown", 
                shiftKey : true
            }
        );
        
        // scroll down the list
        MaxList.dispatchEvent(e);
        MaxList.dispatchEvent(e);
        MaxList.dispatchEvent(e);
        
        // choice
        e = new KeyboardEvent(
            "keydown", 
            {
                bubbles : true, 
                cancelable : true, 
                key : "Enter", 
                char : "Enter", 
                shiftKey : true
            }
        );
        MaxList.dispatchEvent(e);                   
    }
}
</code></pre>
```

> VKomyak (Volt_Nerd)